# At what level in a model object does ActiveRecord not load associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a couple of models that are composites of multiple objects. I basically manage them manually for saves and updates. However, when I select items out, I don't have access to the associated properties of said item. For example:

```
class ObjectConnection < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.get_three_by_location_id location_id
    l=ObjectConnection.find_all_by_location_id(location_id).first(3)
    r=[]
    l.each_with_index do |value, key|
      value[:engine_item]=Item.find(value.engine_id)
      value[:chassis_item]=Item.find(value.chassis_id)
      r << value
    end
    return r
  end
end
```

and each item:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assets, :as => :assetable, :dependent => :destroy
```

When I use the ObjectLocation.find_three_by_location_id, I don't have access to assets whereas if use Item.find(id) in most other situations, I do.

I tried using includes but that didn't seem to do it.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the simplest solution would be to add methods to your `ObjectConnection` model for easy access like so:

```
class ObjectConnection < ActiveRecord::Base

  def engine
    Engine.find(engine_id)
  end

  def chassis
    Chassis.find(chassis_id)
  end

  # rest of class omitted...
```

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking... If this doesn't answer what you're asking, then can you try to be a little bit more clear with what exactly you are trying to accomplish?  Are the `Chassis` and `Engine` mdoels supposed to be polymorphic associations with your `Item` model?

Also, the code you're using above won't work due to the fact that you are trying to dynamically set properties on a model.  It's not your calls to `Item.find` that are failing, it's your calls to `value[:engine_item]=` and `value[:chassis_item]` that are failing.  You would need to modify it to be something like this if you wanted to keep that flow:

```
def self.get_three_by_location_id location_id
  l=ObjectConnection.find_all_by_location_id(location_id).first(3)
  r=[]
  l.each_with_index do |obj_conn, key|
    # at this point, obj_conn is an ActiveRecord object class, you can't dynamically set attributes on it at this point
    value = obj_conn.attributes # returns the attributes of the ObjectConnection as a hash where you can then add additional key/value pairs like on the next 2 lines
    value[:engine_item]=Item.find(value.engine_id)
    value[:chassis_item]=Item.find(value.chassis_id)
    r << value
  end
  r
end
```

But I still think that this whole method seems unnecessary due to the fact that if you setup proper associations on your `ObjectConnection` model to begin with, then you don't need to go and try to handle the associations manually like you're attempting to do here.

Comment: I tried but both engine and chassis are 'items' and I can't have `belongs_to :item, :foreign_key => 'engine_id', belongs_to :item, :foreign_key => 'chassis_id'`. It  would seem the relationship is a `has_one` but, honestly, how to model this is a little bit beyond me. Engine and Chassis are not polymorphic. Right now, there are status field for is_engine, is_chassis. This part is definitely a little ugly but the way it is modelling works very well in other parts of the app.

Comment: It sounds to me like you would be best off making `Item` the superclass, and then making a seperate `Engine` and `Chassis` model that are subclasses of `Item`.  Then specifying a `polymorphic` relationship for your `Item` class (which will trickle down to the other classes).  [Read some more about polymorphic relationships in ActiveRecord here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) on the rails doc site.  If you really want to stick with your current setup (which I wouldn't recommend) then read the bottom portion of my modified answer.

Comment: that part of the code that you mention works fine - outputting correct data in view.

Comment: Maybe editing the relationships does make sense. But really don't want to as this is the only pieces that is not working. Would rather even just do an ajax call in the view to bring in these assets than mucking around with our model at this point. Thx for ideas on this!

Comment: How to load / be able to access associated assets in the view which. I suspect since the ObjectConnection doesn't know about these items explicitly is the issue but I'm not sure.

Comment: Oh I get it.  I think your best solution is to add methods like these to your `ObjectConnection` model:  `def engine` `Item.find(engine_id)` `end`.  Then you can access the objects as if you had set up the polymorphic associations properly.  See my revised answer above.  I still would recommend you look into polymorphic associations at some point though.

Comment: have to run to meeting but thinking something liek this should do it